# Labelling only certain polygon features in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, labeling

The red colored countries in the image are countries i consider highly vulnerable to freshwater shortages. I like to have the name of only these highly vulnerable countries appear on the map, i'd be glad to get responses on how to go about this.
[image]

Comment: See here  the answer https://anitagraser.com/2012/01/09/easier-conditional-labels-in-qgis/

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 8):

Select the Field that contains the country names from the drop-down list of `Label with`, and under `Rendering` Tab, go to `Show label -> Edit`:

[image]

and enter the following expression:

```
"Field_name" = 'High Vulnerable'
```

Where the Field_name is the field that has the classification of water vulnerability.

*Pay attention* to the the double quote marks for the field column name and single quote marks for the string value.

Comment: thanks so much for your efforts, i got the desired result.

Comment: @Learner, if this answer worked for you, please accept it as per the [help centre](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 7):

Another option:

There's full support for filtering labels by an expression. In the labeling tab choose "Rule based labling" from the top drop-down". In that window, Click on the green "+" to add a new rule. Then you can use all the expression options to add and format labels. For example, if the water availability is a numeric field, you could enter something like:
 "water_available" >1000000

Then, of course, choose the country name field as the label.

What's more, you can label different levels of water availability with different color or size labels...

Answer (score 4):

what you want is a rule based labeling. You can use it like this: Tested in QGIS 2.14.3:

[image]

Comment: what software are you using to create that animated GIF?

Comment: @DPSSpatial it works for windows and its called [ScreenToGif](http://screentogif.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @LaughU thanks for the easy to follow through animation. It worked perfectly for me.

Comment: ScreenToGif has now moved to https://www.screentogif.com/

Comment: Love this answer!