# Labelling features based on 2 attributes QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, attribute-table

I'd like to label cities that exceed 10,000 inhabitants. In my attribute table, I have the name of cities in one column, and in another, the amount of inhabitants. Is there a way to write down an expression using two attributes? I've looked around but have only found expressions using one column of the attribute table. This musn't be complicated but my expressions fail every time.

[image]

Comment: I did actually, found a related question for MapInfo, which won't help, and another one using only one attribute instead of 2. That's the reason behind my question

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about precisely what you've tried so far?

Comment: It sounds like you want to only display the city name if the population is greater than 10000. Do you also want to display the population of that city? If you only want to filter the labels look at the answers in this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240842/labelling-only-certain-polygon-features-in-qgis

Comment: @AlexHajnal, my first try was this: if("NAME3" > 10000),"NAME3". which won't work obviously. I'm starting to use the expression window and making a lot of synthax mistakes

Comment: The expression editor window shows all the available fields, commands, etc. in the tree to the right of the edit field.  If you click on any of the items in it you'll get a description of each item, how to use it, etc.; a double-click will add it to your expression,  As for expression syntax, most of the functions, etc. have the syntax `FUNCTION_NAME( arg1, arg2, argn)` and can be nested.  Strings should be enclosed in single quotes while fields get double-quoted.

Comment: Thanks for your input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I typically use is to set the label to the empty string for values that don't match.  For your example table putting the following as the label expression should do what you want:

`IF( "UN_2015_E" >= 10000, "NAME3", '' )`

To include the population as well use something like:

`IF( "UN_2015_E" >= 10000, CONCAT( "NAME3", ' (', "UN_2015_E", ')' ) , '' )`

Answer (score 3):

Use an expression like:

```
concat(NAME1,' | ',UN_2015_E)
```

[image]

Comment: What program did you use for the annotations?

Comment: @Baswein I use a (quite old and unmaintained, but still excellent) program called HotShot (sourceforge.net/projects/hotshots)